# Ansible - How to overcome winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 400

Tags: powershell, jenkins, networking, ansible

Trying to overcome error message:

```
winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. 
Code 400 error message was failed
```

- I have a laptop that run Docker with Jenkins container in it.
- The Jenkins container has an Ansible service.
- The Jenkins pipeline is running against VMs in a VCenter server in the organization.
- All the VMs are Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 and Up
  (Should I have run it inside the Jenkins container? Or in the deployed VMs?)

My pipeline start with:

- `PLAY [revert vmware vcenter lab]`
- `PLAY [copy files to lab]`

The other plabooks are responsible to install the files and configure the system

The `group_var > all.yml` file include the following winRM details:

```yaml
ansible_user: bob
ansible_password: sponge
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_winrm_scheme: http
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: false
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 70
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 60
```

First *revert* playbook is passed,

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
vm1: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm2: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm3: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The *copy* playbook is failed

```
PLAY [copy files to lab] ***************************************************

TASK [tfs : Download TFS build Server.msi"] ************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. 
The error was: winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 400
fatal: [vm1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. 
The error was: winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 400
fatal: [vm2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
changed: [vm3]

TASK [tfs : Download TFS build Config.zip"] ************************************
skipping: [vm3]

TASK [tfs : Download TFS build file2.msi] *****************************
changed: [vm3]

TASK [tfs : Download TFS build file3.msi] ******************************
skipping: [vm3]

TASK [tfs : Download TFS build file1.msi] *******************
skipping: [vm3]

TASK [tfs : Unzip Config.zip file] *********************************************
skipping: [vm3]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
vm3: ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm1: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm2: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:351)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate2(ACL.java:451)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Ansible playbook execution failed

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
vm1: ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm2: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm3: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And times that the copy playbook log shows failures at the begning of the playbook, like that:

```
PLAY [copy files to lab] ***************************************************

[WARNING]: ERROR DURING WINRM SEND INPUT - attempting to recover:
WinRMTransportError Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 400

...

Checking the Lab's machines shows that not all the files were copied to the machines.
If I restart the copy stage - it solves the problem but not the root of the problem.
```

The `retries` option in the copy task is not activated when error code 400 is occur, and the task is marked as completed. Here is one of the copy task that I'm using:

```yaml
- name: Download TFS build Server.msi"
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      $definitionName = "{{ tfs_version }}-Server-CI"
      $buildQuality = "{{ tfs_quality }}"
      $type = "msi"
      $teamProject = "Product"
      $path = "C:\files\Server.msi"
      $username = '{{ tfs_user }}'
      $password = '{{ tfs_password }}'
      $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -Force -AsPlainText
      $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $securePassword)
      $uncBuildServer = "\\fl2.corp.com"

      $definitions = Invoke-RestMethod "http://almtfs.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/$($teamProject)/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0-preview" -Method Get -Credential $credentials
      $definitionId = $definitions.value | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $definitionName} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id

      $builds = Invoke-RestMethod "http://almtfs.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/$($teamProject)/_apis/build/builds?Definitions=$($definitionId)&api-version=2.0-preview" -Method Get -Credential $credentials
      $buildsCount = $builds.count
      $msiFiles = $null
      $i = 0

      NET USE $uncBuildServer $password /USER:$username

      do 
      {
        if ($definitionName -eq "Trunk-Server-CI")
        {
            $build = $builds.Value | Where-Object {($_.status -eq 'completed') -and ($_.result -eq 'succeeded')} | Sort-Object -Property queueTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        elseif ($definitionName -ne "Trunk-Server-CI" -and $buildQuality -eq "latestGreen")
        {
            $build = $builds.Value | Where-Object {($_.status -eq 'completed') -and ($_.result -eq 'succeeded')} | Sort-Object -Property queueTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        elseif ($definitionName -ne "Trunk-Server-CI" -and $buildQuality -eq "Hotfix")
        {
            $build = $builds.Value | Where-Object {($_.status -eq 'completed') -and ($_.result -eq 'succeeded') -and ($_.quality -eq 'Hotfix')} | Sort-Object -Property queueTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        elseif ($definitionName -ne "Trunk-Server-CI" -and $buildQuality -eq "Released")
        {
            $build = $builds.Value | Where-Object {($_.status -eq 'completed') -and ($_.result -eq 'succeeded') -and ($_.quality -eq 'Released')} | Sort-Object -Property queueTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        elseif ($definitionName -ne "Trunk-Server-CI" -and $buildQuality -eq "Internal")
        {
            $build = $builds.Value | Where-Object {($_.status -eq 'completed') -and ($_.result -eq 'succeeded') -and ($_.quality -eq 'Internal')} | Sort-Object -Property queueTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        else
        {
            $build = $builds.Value | Where-Object {($_.status -eq 'completed') -and ($_.result -eq 'succeeded')} | Sort-Object -Property queueTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip $i | Select-Object -First 1
        }

          $dropFolder = @(
              "\\fl2.corp..com\sw\prod\drop\$($definitionName)\$($build.buildNumber)"
              "\\fl2.corp..com\sw\$($teamProject)\drop\$($definitionName)\$($build.buildNumber)"
          ) | Where-Object {Test-Path $_}

          $msiFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter 'Server.msi' -Recurse -Path "$dropFolder\Install\Wix" | Where-Object {($_.FullName -like "*x64*") -or ($_.FullName -like 'Win64*')} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -Verbose

          If ($msiFiles -eq $null)
          {
              Write-Host "TFS-Build Drop Folder: $($dropFolder) is missing Install folder"
              Write-Host "Skipping to the next green build"

              $i++
          }
          elseif ($i -eq $buildsCount)
          {
              Write-Host "last green build file was not found in tfs build server"
          }
          else
          {
              Write-Host "last green build file was found"
              Write-Host "TFS-Build Drop Folder: $($dropFolder)"    
          }            
      }
      while (($msiFiles -eq $null) -or ($i -eq $buildsCount))

      $serverMsi = $msiFiles

      if (-NOT (Test-Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE\files\"))
      {
          mkdir "$env:HOMEDRIVE\files\" -Force
      }

      Copy-Item -Path $serverMsi -Destination "$env:HOMEDRIVE\files\" -Force -Verbose

      NET USE * /delete /y

      Test-Path $path -PathType Leaf
      
  when: "'center' in group_names"
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  register: results
  retries: 5
  delay: 30
  until: results is not failed
```

a. Why do I get error code 400 and how can I solve\overcome it? 
b. If I can't solve error code 400, how can I 'retry' the task till it succeed?

01/01/2023 - Update: I ran the following scripts on my lab's machines:
[ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1](https://gist.github.com/nikhilsingnurkar/9776116d44446a3f5da64d71cfafe57f) [winRMbatch.bat](https://gist.github.com/juanje/8496054) - I see less error code 400 now. But, the the ansible retry mechanism isn't activated. You can see below that the task was failed at the beggining

```
TASK [tfs : Download TFS build file1.msi] *******************

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 400

fatal: [vm1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Comment: Every Server is different.  Error 400 indicates the Request doesn't meet the server requirements.  Which can mean one of 3 things 1) The URL is bad.  Some servers require parameters after the question mark on the URL and you are missing some parameters 2) The HTTP headers are not correct 3) The body of request is not correct or the type of data isn't consistent with the headers.  Best way of finding issue is to debug the server.  Often the more detail info can be found in the Event Viewer of Server.